# GDPR Cookie Compliance Javascript Callbacks

Tags: javascript, cookies, callback, addeventlistener

This is related to implementing GDPR compliance on a Joomla 3.9.13 website, but i'm sure it's similar regardless of the platform.

I've been looking at https://github.com/osano/cookieconsent and it seems to meet all the legal requirements, and also looks good. They have a [configuration wizard](https://www.osano.com/cookieconsent/download/) available on their website and it's very easy to use, the trouble is there's additional code required in order to make the popup actually do anything apart from popup.

Their documentation covers [callback hooks](https://www.osano.com/cookieconsent/documentation/disabling-cookies/) that need to be implemented in order to disable cookies.. something I have no experience in.

My understanding is that **all** cookies should be blocked on the page *until the user explicitly agrees to them*. So looking the browser console > cookies on page load it should be empty until I click accept, then cookies will appear. I can't get this part to work. Whenever my page loads so do all of the cookies, I have tried and my code is below;

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    window.cookieconsent.initialise({
        "palette": {
            "popup": {
                "background": "#000"
            },
            "button": {
                "background": "#f1d600"
            }
        },
        "position": "bottom-left",
        "type": "opt-out",
        "content": {
            "href": "cookie-policy.html"
        },
        onInitialise: function(status) {
            var type = this.options.type;
            var didConsent = this.hasConsented();
            if (type == 'opt-in' && didConsent) {
                // enable cookies
                window['ga-disable-GA_TRACKING_ID'] = false;
            }
            if (type == 'opt-out' && !didConsent) {
                // disable cookies
                console.log('cookies disabled');
                window['ga-disable-GA_TRACKING_ID'] = true;
            }
        },
        onStatusChange: function(status, chosenBefore) {
            var type = this.options.type;
            var didConsent = this.hasConsented();
            if (type == 'opt-in' && didConsent) {
                window['ga-disable-GA_TRACKING_ID'] = false;
            }
            if (type == 'opt-out' && !didConsent) {
                // disable cookies
                window['ga-disable-GA_TRACKING_ID'] = true;
            }
        },
        onRevokeChoice: function() {
            var type = this.options.type;
            if (type == 'opt-in') {
                // disable cookies
                window['ga-disable-GA_TRACKING_ID'] = true;
            }
            if (type == 'opt-out') {
                // enable cookies
                window['ga-disable-GA_TRACKING_ID'] = false;
            }
        },
    })
});
</script>
```

This code doesn't really do anything apart from display the popup with the text / colours I have set above.

What do I need to change in order to get it working?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I know this is a little old and the repository has been updated, but did this end up working out for you? I need to add compliance for everything so I'm looking into a "one size fits all" solution

Comment: Yea I got it working by blocking all cookies until the user explicitly agreed to them, then they are enabled.